# Sublime text: error while loading shared libraries

Tags: debian, sublime-text-3, sublime-text

When I try to run sublime text 3 (installed with the [official instructions](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/linux_repositories.html#apt)) in a new debian sid chroot, it does not start, outputting:

```
/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text: error while loading shared libraries: libX11.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How do I start sublime text?

Answer (score 2):

The sublime deb package does not declare any dependencies, so you need to install those yourself, by running

```
sudo apt install libglib2.0-0 libx11-6 libcairo2 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libgtk2.0-0
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following workaround. I am using **CentOS.9**, and had installed Sublime-Text with snap.

I had to uninstall sublime with command:
`sudo snap remove sublime-text`

Then I installed Sublime Text with **yum**:

1. Install the GPG key

---

`sudo rpm -v --import https://download.sublimetext.com/sublimehq-rpm-pub.gpg`

2. Select channel to use:

---

`sudo yum-config-manager --add-repo https://download.sublimetext.com/rpm/stable/x86_64/sublime-text.repo`

(In case **yum-config-manager** is not recognized, try installing **yum-utils**: `yum install yum-utils`)

3. Install Sublime Text

---

`sudo yum install sublime-text`

This worked well for me.
Follow official Sublime Text for other OS's (https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/linux_repositories.html#yum).
Best regards.